# How to put a "failed" notification on reactjs

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, reactjs, fetch

The react I have is connected to C# asp.net for an api, it doesnt delete the data when the foreign key is connected to the other tables in the database but if the key is not connected on the other tables it can delete the data, I hope you get my point ... so here is the problem my ajax send the data to be deleted on the api 
using this code

```
export const deleter = (url, params) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, api) => {
        api += 'api/';
        return fetch(`${api}${url}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        })

        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => dispatch(departmentResult(result, types.DELETER)))
        .then(function(response) {
             NotificationManager.success('The department is deleted', 'Department Deleted ')   
         },
         function (error) {
            NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')   
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
             NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')   
         // any error from "doing stuff" will show up here
         console.error(error);
    });
    }
}
```

however it always shows the success notification even if it wasn't deleted, I dont know why, I am trying to output an error notification when not deleted . but the error part of this code is not working . hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is fetch API's expected behaviour. From docs:

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is
>   encountered, although this usually means permission issues or similar
>   — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example.

This means, if your asp.net web api returns a common HTTP error status like 500 or 400, it will not be deemed as error. To catch those, you could do something like that:

```
.then(result => dispatch(departmentResult(result, types.DELETER)))
    .then(function(response) {
         if (response.status == 200){
             NotificationManager.success('The department is deleted', 'Department Deleted ')
         } else if (response.status == 500) {
             NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')
         } else {
             NotificationManager.error('Sorry, something went wrong', 'ERROR! ')
         }
     },
     function (error) {
        NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
         NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')   
     // any error from "doing stuff" will show up here
     console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering however I dont know why it only shows `(NotificationManager.error('Sorry, something went wrong', 'ERROR! ')`

Answer (score 0):

it turns out my construction of code was wrong

```
export const deleter = (url, params) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, api) => {
        api += 'api/';
        return fetch(`${api}${url}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        })      
        .then(function(response) {
         if (response.status <= 200){
             NotificationManager.success('The department is deleted', 'Department Deleted ')
         } else if (response.status <= 500) {
             NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')
         } else {
             NotificationManager.error('Sorry, something went wrong', 'ERROR! ')
         }
     },
     function (error) {
        NotificationManager.error('Sorry but this has already been used', 'ERROR! ')
     })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => dispatch(departmentResult(result, types.DELETER)));

    }
}
```